# is there a way to hide a texture using libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

i have a game where you are trying to collect objects, each time you collect it I want the object to hide all the way TILL IT IS OUT OF THE SCREEN. Currently i have

```
if(!collision){
            batch.draw(mysteryCloud, pos.x, pos.y, 64, 64);
        }
```

in this case when i use the code it hides the for as long as they are colliding, but sometimes they  have already collided and the object is still not out of the screen. So the object just reappears I want something like this:
if(collision){
dont draw till it the object is out of the screen}

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The texture shouldn't be drawn to the screen unless it was drawn on the most recent frame. Are you making sure to clear the screen on every call to the `render()` method?

Comment: Have you implemented a logic to check if the object is out of the screen? What direction are the objects moving? x or y or both?